# twitter-bootstrap JQuery error

Tags: jquery, highcharts, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am using twitter bootstrap rails with jQuery 1.7 
When I load my project it works fine, except for an error in jQuery file. I am assuming this is is affecting my highcharts and the graphs are not displayed.

However can somebody help me resolve this issue:
This is from line 633 inside jquery.extend() function:
632.        var name, i = 0,
633.            length = object.length,
634.            isObj = length === undefined || jQuery.isFunction( object );

Here is the error:
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'undefined.length')

Can somebody please help?

Best,

Comment: What is the code which is given the error. Does the error refer to a line number or something like that? Would be helpfull.

Comment: It was jQuery min version, I replaced it with jquery full. It gives me an error at line 633:
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'object.length')

And the line 633 is in jQuery.extend function:

.
.
each: function( object, callback, args ) {
        var name, i = 0,
            length = object.length,
            isObj = length === undefined || jQuery.isFunction( object );

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using?

Comment: I am working on rails, hence I'm sorry, I can't really paste the entire code. I have a single view page which does not have this error, it loads the chart successfully!
Trying to figure out what is different about this page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured the problem out. It was a minor fault in my JS handling. I was not checking for existence of an array created out of a div at my front end.

changed the code from

$.each($myArr, function(key,value){
.
.
.
});

to

if($myArr){
$.each($myArr, function(key,value){
.
.
.
});
}

This was a common JS file that was loaded to a number of views. Changing this worked! :)